# Adding bibliographic reference to ipe image

Tags: bibtex, cite-package, ipe

Is there a way to add a hyperlink to a reference from a bibliography (bib/bbl) in an image (created using IPE)?

I want to create an image with text that when clicked directs to a reference in the bibliography in the document.

Comment: What is IPE?  And have you tried putting `\label` or some `hyperref` command in a `.bib` entry and then `\ref`-ing or `\hyperref`-ing it?

Comment: Place bibliographic information under the picture or within the caption.

Comment: @Johannes_B -- I agree that is what should (normally) be done, but I don't think it is an answer to the second sentence in the question.

Comment: @jon You already mentioned hyperref.

Comment: @Johannes_B -- Oh, I see.  My mistake.

Comment: This is IPE: http://ipe.otfried.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.graphics.ipe.general/1113

You can use the \psfrag commands to do what you want.
Create the figure  and put placeholders for the \ref 
or \cite commands you want
(eg, cite1, ref1 etc) in IPE.
Then in your latex document when 
including the figure you can 
replace the instances of cite1, ref1 etc
 using psfrag with whatever latex command you choose.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the IPE figure, just put in `\cite{}`, `\ref{}`, the same way as you do in the LaTeX file.

After finishing your LaTeX main file, open `main.aux`, copy `\newlabel{sec:section}{II}` or `\bibcite{article}{1}` to the Edit->Document properties->Latex preambles. Run LaTeX again for IPE, then it works.